# what does $styles means in drupal?

Tags: commerce, theming

I am new in drupal.. please let me know what is the meaning of

$styles

in drupal html.tpl.php file..
If we want to add new css and js from where we can add this..

PLeas help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$styles` is a variable. It's initialised and made available to the template via the core [`template_process_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) function.

To add CSS you can use [`drupal_add_css()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7), and to add JS you can use [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7). Either can also be accomplished using the `#attached` property in a render array (which is actually the recommended approach these days), or by including `scripts`/`stylesheets` keys in your theme's .info file.

*Where* you can add it depends on what context you need to add it in. This could be page callback, one of many alter hooks, a process or preprocess function, and so on. If your new CSS applies to every page, it might make sense to use the info file method.

Alternatively, if you want to override the CSS of an existing theme, you can create a sub-theme and simply modify the appropriate CSS files without having to use the API.

If you're brand new to Drupal there are a few concepts you need to understand before any of this will make sense. I recommend reading the following:

- [Theming Guide](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme)
- [Preprocess and process functions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430)
- [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760)
- [Writing theme .info files](https://www.drupal.org/node/171205)
- [Creating a sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125)